# Powermock Issue while using whenNew

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:application-context.xml")
@PrepareForTest({})
public class test 
{

B b = new B();

b.Calculate("Test","Test");

//some assertions
}


public class B {

public boolean Calculate(String x, String y){

Return true

}

}
```

Here I am trying to write JUnit for method calculate of class B. So I create object of class B and call the calculate method. My problem is I want to test the calculate method without using the new object. I tried below it doesn't works

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockRunnerDelegate(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:application-context.xml")
@PrepareForTest({Test.class})
public class Test {

B myObjectMock  = Mockito.mock(B.class);

PowerMockito.whenNew(B.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(myObjectMock);

B b = new B();

b.Calculate("Test","Test");

}
```

Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: Please use meaningful names. Especially using **Test** as name for a test ... super bad idea. You are immediately creating a potential conflict with the @ Test annotation . Dont you ever do that. Use names that **mean** something. And class names start UpperCase. Always. So having `test` and `Test`... woha. That just asks for trouble.

Comment: Beyond that - dont put up fragments of code! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the [edit] link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: Add B.class to preaprefortest annotation